# Regex to check if second char are 0-6, second fifth and sixth are 04 and exactly 6 digits long?

Tags: regex

I need a regex to only match dates that are Jan-June and in the year 2004. In the format 021204 would be matched while a date such as 021205 or 071204 would not be matched. The directory that contains the files also contains files named with 7 or 8 digits that are not valid dates so it needs to be only 6 digits long. This is what I tried:

```
\d\[0-6]{2}\[4]{6}\
```

This regex is not working correctly, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

`0[1-6](?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])04`

---

**Some notes:**

a character class `[]` only matches one character.

`[0-9]{3}` matches `000-999` because I specified for it to repeat 3 times with `{3}`

It does NOT match `0-999` because the left hand side of the range only has `{1}` character.

If I used `[0-9]{1,3}` it would match anything from `0-9`, `00-99` or `000-999`.

So in this instance, you need to put `([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` for the days in the month to signify `1-31`.
If you break it down you can see:

01-9 = `0[1-9]`

10-29 = `[12][0-9]`

30-31 =`3[01]`

Comment: your pattern as is will not match 010104 because it does not allow the day range of 01 - 09

Comment: Nice pickup, I've edited it.
It'd be cool if there was some way to reverse regex and print out everything that it CAN match...

Comment: This works wonderfully! Thank you. I didn't know that ] \d only matches one character I thought I could specify the range with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
^0[1-6](([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))04$
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
^0[1-6](?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])04$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ensure that the dates are valid (e.g. no Feb 30 or Jun 31) the following should enforce the proper number of days in each month:

```
^0(?:(?:[135](?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|(?:[46](0[1-9]|[12]\d|30))|2(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d))04$
```